# iOS app thinks I'm not registered on a site until I try to register

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, ios-app

First: I love the iOS app. It works quite well. Thanks for all the work on it!

Next: it is very confused. When I try to add a comment on Software Recommendations (where it lets me vote and everything), this happens:

[image]

But tapping on 'join' makes this happen:

[image]

And I still can't comment. Could this please be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interestingly, this bug happened only for you because you have accounts on so many SE sites ;-)

This should be fixed **in 0.1.55.**

Comment: Wow, that's... weird. What kind of bug causes that?

Comment: We were only fetching the first 100 or so accounts (including metas) but you had a little over 100

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks for fixing it!