# iOS app blocking actions with "you must join this site" message for sites I belong to

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

[image: Hey, guys - it's me. I work here and stuff. Guys?]

This is happening only since last update (or one in the last day or so). Seeing it on multiple sites, and quit => reopen didn't work, nor did a restart.

EDIT:  As pointed out by @Anthony, this appears to be a dupe of [this report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230123/ios-app-thinks-im-not-registered-on-a-site-until-i-try-to-register), but since that's marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), it might be a different bug causing the same output?  I'm happy to self-close as dupe, but want to make sure we ID the new cause.

Comment: [Same thing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230123/ios-app-thinks-im-not-registered-on-a-site-until-i-try-to-register) happening again?

Comment: There was an unannounced update to 1.0.0.67. You'll need to delete and download again to update. Does that solve it?

Answer (score 1):

We have fixed this issue a while back. It seems like it only happened to users who belonged to a large number of sites (like yourself). Locally we were only reading the first page of those accounts, so the app wrongly thought you hadn't joined them.